# AWS RDS MySQL: Populate Timezone Tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, timezone

I'm using an AWS RDS MySql (5.7.19) installation and I need to do some date conversions.  Most docs say that you need to have the timezone tables populated, to do anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc

Is there a way to set the timezone tables in this current setup?

I can do things like

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '-04:00' );
```

But I'm concerned about the daylight savings times coming into play.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about `SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), @@session.time_zone, 'America/New_York' );`?

Comment: @ceejayoz It returns null.  When I run "SELECT @@session.time_zone;", it gives me a value of SYSTEM.

Comment: It sounds like you MySQL time zone table is not populated, you need to feed it data as by default it’s empty. Look at mysql documentation for details.